# C++ getting keyboard adapter when using two keyboards, determine where the keypress come from

Tags: c++, macros, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I would like to know how to detect the keyboard adapter on Windows when using two keyboards, that a key eg. W was pressed on first or on the second keyboard.

Can anybody help me how to do it?
I would like to use a cheap solution for macros. I would plan to bind macros for entrie second keyboard, when somebody press key W (just for example), keybaord would type a world uint8_t.

Comment: In the two thousand pages that comprise the current C++ standard, there is not a single mention of anything called a "keyboard adapter". You will likely have to dig through the mountains of technical documentation for Microsoft Windows, to locate whatever you need to do to access the hardware at a very low level, open the required device drivers yourself, manually, and read the hardware devices yourself. Probably have to write code to decode keyscans, I would venture to guess. You will find MSDN documentation down the hall, last door on your left.

Comment: This is what I was afraid, but thanks for answer.

Comment: I solved this issue with using a STM32 NUCLEO board as USB Host, where I connected the second keyboard and transfer the data via UART to PC. In PC I process the data from serial and with SendInput type the desired text. If somebody need the code, write here or send me a message. I googled a lot how this could be possible with direct USB connection, but I haven't found anything useful. It must be possible of course but I'm not going to dig into kernel.