# Is there a way to read data from barcode reader on windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to read from a barcode reader in an electron.js application.
Using node-hid, I was able to discover the device. But, the device is registered as a keyboard in windows.
For security reasons, windows won't let me access keyboards and mice.

A workaround is to read keyboard strikes. But to be honest this is not a good workaround since the user is also using his keyboard.

Comment: The scary answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139696/c-getting-keyboard-adapter-when-using-two-keyboards-determine-where-the-keypr

Comment: I guess this is where one can start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerrawinputdevices